# Removing Const: Casting from std::shared_ptr<const T> to T

Tags: c++, templates, casting, constants, const-cast

Is there a way to cast from `T = std::shared_ptr<const A>` to `TCV = A` please? I used this:

```
template<typename T> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
concept is_shared = is_shared_ptr<T>::value;

template<typename T, typename U>
requires is_shared<T> and is_shared<U>
static void operate(const T& x, const U& y)
{
    using TCV = std::remove_cv<typename decltype(T)::element_value>;
    using UCV = std::remove_cv<typename decltype(U)::element_value>;
    forward_operate(const_cast<TCV>(*x), const_cast<UCV>(*y));
};
```

signature of `forward_operate` is:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
forward_operate(A&, B&);
```

This code doesn't work (ofc), could you please help? Also should I ever do this ever (I need to do this)?

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks!

Comment: _That's a bummer_ Why?  Why are you so addicted to casts?

Comment: Because I am adding too many constraints on my code :) I want to be the only one casting and the user has const stuff! Otherwise I might have to take a design pattern course.

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you're trying to do here, but if the user `const` qualifies something, she probably has a reason...

Answer (score 0):

> Casting from std::shared_ptr to T

You cannot cast from a (smart) pointer to the pointed type. You must indirect through the pointer to access the pointed object.

Based on the attempted code, looks like you're trying to do this:

```
forward_operate(
    const_cast<typename T::element_type&>(*x),
    const_cast<typename U::element_type&>(*y));
```

Do keep in mind that casting away const is a strong code smell. Don't do this unless you understand what it does.